# Error when install an extension for Visual Studio 11 beta

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have created an extension for Visual Studio 11 beta using Managed Package Framework for Project 2010. Extension works fine when is tested in Visual Studio 11 Experimental instance but fails to work when installed. It appears in Extension Manager but not in Visual Studio About Box and also the new project created by extension does not appear in New Project dialog. In Visual Studio log file appears the message

```
<description>Error in Template (C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\...\XYZ_Project_Template.zip), file (XYZ_Project_Template.vstemplate).  Unregistered ProjectType (XYZProject).  This can be caused by an incorrect ProjectType or because the project type package is not installed.</description>
```

Have someone any clue about how to resolve this? All dlls and other extension files seems to be in place.

Comment: Note that the product doesn't have a name yet. Also, the "11" in "Visual Studio 11" does not refer to the year 2011. It would be unlikely for Microsoft to name a new product after an old year.

Comment: Microsoft uses the term "Visual Studio 11 beta" on their page. http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads

Comment: Yes, but they don't use "Visual Studio 2011 beta". The version number of Visual Studio 2010 is "10". The version number of Visual Studio 11 is "11". That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Found the result myself:
devenv /setup
must be run during install to determine Visual Studio 11 to scan for extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to run devenv /setup to get a new extension to load. If you are having load issues, I would check a few other things before resorting to that "big hammer".

- Run Visual Studio with the /log switch and then check the `ActivityLog.xml` file in `%appdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0`
- In `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0` delete the `ComponentModelCache` directory (close VS before doing this)

Good luck!